# Consume WCF Service as external Content Type through Sharepoint 2013

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

I am trying to consume a WCF Service with SharePoint 2013. But when I try to add the Content Type with the SharePoint Developer to the BDC I get the following error.

[image]

This message means something like "unexpected internal error in Business Data Connectivity Service: There are no Adresses available for this Application"

In the Headline the message means: "Error while Access the WCF-Service. URL: ...."

But I have tested the Service local with the WCF Test Client. (Everything is working) Also i have checked if the SharePoint Server can reach the URL I have defined.

Another interesting fakt is that the Designer was able to create the Content Type but couldn´t parse it ...

[image]

When I try to refresh the created Content Type I got a slightly different error message. The Details are equal but there is also a line saying that "A proxyassemblie couldn´t be created"

I am at the end of my knowledge can anybody imagine the fault?
If you Need more ressources (like the WCF Definition) just ask!

bg

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The Service "Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service" wasn´t started ...
No everything is working

bg